# How to normalize a table to range [0;1]

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, normalize

I have a table in matlab , and I want to normalize data between 0 and 1
this is a row of my table:

> 6 148 72  35  0   33.6000000000000    0.627000000000000   50

What is the best way to normalize data,
and which one is better, 
normalize by each coloumn or normalize all cell that influence together ?

**EDIT on 5-24-2016**
i just needed to normalize my data to get specific range of value

Comment: It depends.....

Comment: It depends on what your data represent. If each column is a separate meansure / variable then your should probably normalise the columns independently. When you say *table* do you mean you are using a MATLAB `table` data-structure or is this just a regular matrix because it's a lot easier if it's just a matrix...

Comment: I used pima data set

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Pima+Indians+Diabetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization could either mean (a) data obtained on different scales are aligned/adjusted in order to enable comparison, or (b) try to align the statistical distribution of data to Normal distribution.

In this dataset, if you *have* to normalize, then it is column-wise. Mean and variance seem to be important features here though. To normalize column-wise:

```
m = max(D); % D is your dataset matrix
normD = zeros(size(D)); % Here are your normalized values
for i = 1:length(D)
    normD(:,i) = D(:,i)./m(i)
end
```

A faster way to do this is without loops: `D./repmat(max(D),size(D,1),1)`

Comment: Undefined function 'max' for input arguments of type 'table'.